# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Visual Studio C# ASP.Net projects on the **same** machine - one authenticates to AD OK the other does not.
Because they are on the same machine I am ruling out the wider environment and looking at the web.config file. 
I copied the working Web.Config over the non-working one and still it does not authenticate.

System.Web is the same version in both projects.

When published to the live domain, both sites authenticate OK to AD - which is, again, odd.

Any ideas where I should be looking?

config file from the project which does **not** authenticate:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="EntitySpaces" type="EntitySpaces.Interfaces.esConfigSettings, EntitySpaces.Core">
            <section name="connectionInfo" type="EntitySpaces.Interfaces.esConfigSettings, EntitySpaces.Interfaces" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
            <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <EntitySpaces>
        <connectionInfo default="LIVE">
            <connections>
                <add name="DEV" providerMetadataKey="esDefault" sqlAccessType="StoredProcedure" provider="EntitySpaces.SqlClientProvider" providerClass="DataProvider" connectionString="User Id=XXX; Password=XXX; Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=XXX" databaseVersion="2005" />
                <add name="LIVE" providerMetadataKey="esDefault" sqlAccessType="StoredProcedure" provider="EntitySpaces.SqlClientProvider" providerClass="DataProvider" connectionString="User Id=XXX; Password=XXX; Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=XXX" databaseVersion="2005" />
        <add name="TEST" providerMetadataKey="esDefault" sqlAccessType="StoredProcedure" provider="EntitySpaces.SqlClientProvider" providerClass="DataProvider" connectionString="User Id=XXX; Password=XXX; Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=XXX" databaseVersion="2005" />
            </connections>
        </connectionInfo>
    </EntitySpaces>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v13.2.Core, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v13.2.Core, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <httpModules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </httpModules>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="LDAPUserName" value="XXX=="/>
        <add key="LDAPPassword" value="XXX"/>
        <add key="DebugLogging" value="false" />
        <add key="AvailableUsersADGroup" value="APPAllUsers" />
        <add key="DefaultSendEmailToRequestor" value="false" />
        <add key="DefaultSendEmailToOrganiser" value="true" />
        <add key="ExchangeServer" value="XXX" />
        <add key="ExchangeUserName" value="XXX" />
        <add key="ExchangePassword" value="XXX" />
        <add key="EmailSubjectSuffix" value="Clarion Online Forms - " />
        <add key="ClarionITServices" value="XXX" />
        <add key="URL" value="http://businessapps/OnlineForms" />
        <add key="LogoURL" value="\\mcssrv01\Support\LinkedImages\OnlineFormsLogo.png" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.2, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <devExpress>
        <settings rightToLeft="false" doctypeMode="Xhtml" />
        <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="false" />
        <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" />
        <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
    </devExpress>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you please put your web.config code here?

Comment: config file added, although I don't think this is the issue as I copied the working web.config over and it still did not authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Solution!]

I've learn't something new here! The properties for the project *were* set to allow anonymous authentication. This must override the web config in visual studio and hence explain why copying the config file didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

We have had issues that on first page load (especially if a user goes in directly to a menu page).  Try and let it load and then check (via a button) that it is still .isauth.  Then maybe you can call a later event (after page load).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rule out the wider environment.

The site that is allowing anonymous authentication is presumably configured so that:

- IIS allows anonymous authentication
- The IUSR_... account has permission to access whatever pages you're testing.

The site that doesn't allow anonymous authentication may be denying it for any of the following reasons:

- IIS doesn't allow anonymous authentication
- The IUSR_... account doesn't have permission for whatever pages you're testing
- web.config contains an authorization element that denies access to the pages you're testing.

and perhaps other reasons I haven't thought of.

If both sites work in the live domain, that suggests the live domain is configured differently - this is not necessarily "odd".

Comment: Appreciate your comment @Joe but the web configs (and indeed the live IIS environment) is set to disallow anon authentication - it was just my csproj file.